# Is there a workaround to log4j rolling issue?

Tags: log4j2

I'm using a daily rolling policy with log4j2 with a TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.
The log must roll each day at midnight.
I'm using the example except that I have a timezone Europe/Paris.

https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-rollingfileappender-example/

> To enable the daily rolling, log4j2 does not include the
> DailyRollingFileAppender which was present in earlier log4j. To
> rollover logs on daily basis, set interval to 1 in
> TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.

```xml
<RollingFile
  name="rollingFile"
  fileName="${LOG_DIR}/application.log"
     filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/application.%d{dd-MMM}{Europe/Paris}.log.gz"
  ignoreExceptions="false">
  <PatternLayout>
      <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}{Europe/Paris} %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
</RollingFile>
```

I'm facing the issue that instead of rolling at midnight Paris Time, it rolls at GMT which is 22:00 on the previous day.
I found that issue that could be related :
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1631

On that issue, the reporter seems to report the exact same issue except that he was using a different timezone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26707928/8315843

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing your own `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` to correctly roll over files based taking timezone into account should not be that hard to achieve.

See [this](https://github.com/mushkevych/log4j2plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/log4j2plugin/FTimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.java) example for additional information